# Combobox issue in ZK Framework

Tags: combobox, zk, zul

When i click on combo box then options are opening below this combo box

when i am scrolling the window with the help of mouse scroller then window is scrolling down but combo box option is present at the same place. Below of this combo box option value is showing below the middle name

look here for details [Click here](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/85535/combobox-issue-in-zk-framework/)

fiddle example [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2p168oo/1-Another-new-ZK-fiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a known issue ([see tracker](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-172)), currently you need to sync the position yourself.

e.g.,

```
<zk>
    <script><![CDATA[
        function addSyncScroll (wgtId, parentId, add) {
            var wgt = zk.Widget.$('#'+wgtId),
                parentWgt = zk.Widget.$('#'+parentId);
            if (wgt && parentWgt) {
                var cbxToSync = parentWgt._cbxToSync,
                    idx;
                if (!cbxToSync) {
                    initSyncScroll(parentWgt);
                }
                cbxToSync = parentWgt._cbxToSync;

                if (cbxToSync) {
                    if (!wgt._syncPopupScroll) {
                        wgt._syncPopupScroll = function () {
                            zk(wgt.getPopupNode_()).position(wgt.getInputNode(), "after_start");
                        }
                    }
                    if (add) {
                        if (cbxToSync.indexOf(wgt) < 0)
                            cbxToSync.push(wgt);
                    } else {
                        if ((idx = cbxToSync.indexOf(wgt) < 0) > -1) {
                            cbxToSync.splice(idx, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function initSyncScroll (parentWgt) {
            parentWgt._cbxToSync = [];
            parentWgt.$n().onscroll = function (event) {
                var cbxToSync = parentWgt._cbxToSync;
                for (var i = 0; i < cbxToSync.length; i++) {
                    cbxToSync[i]._syncPopupScroll();
                }
            }
        }
    ]]></script>
    <div width="200px" height="300px">
        <div id="parent" width="100%" vflex="1" style="overflow:auto;">
            <label value="Some text" />
            <textbox value="01" />
            <textbox value="02" />
            <textbox value="03" />
            <combobox>
                <attribute name="onOpen"><![CDATA[
                    Clients.evalJavaScript("addSyncScroll('"+self.getUuid()+"', '"+parent.getUuid()+"', "+self.isOpen()+")");
                ]]></attribute>
                <comboitem label="Simple and Rich" />
                <comboitem label="Cool!" />
                <comboitem label="Ajax and RIA" />
            </combobox>
            <textbox value="04" />
            <textbox value="05" />
            <textbox value="06" />
            <textbox value="07" />
            <textbox value="08" />
            <textbox value="09" />
            <textbox value="10" />
            <textbox value="11" />
            <textbox value="12" />
            <textbox value="13" />
            <textbox value="14" />
            <textbox value="15" />
        </div>
    </div>

</zk>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Known issue in ZK you can check here [ZK Issue trcker](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-1552)

May be it will take some time and in future releases we will get some workaround ,According to @Ben it will fix in furture.

Comment: Actually I do not know the future, just know there is no easy efficient way to fix it currently. (Regarding efficient, means the performance is good)

Comment: Ok you mean right now no any fixes soon we have to see solution which provided by you

Comment: I mean, maybe someone will fix it in the future, but not sure when?